# Is it possible to specify compatible iOS devices - by model - in App Store?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

I'm currently writing an application that is only supported on iPad Air 1 + 2. I am checking for device compatibility in code, but is there a way to also specify that on the App Store?

I haven't been able to find anything past `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`, which only specifies certain characteristics that the device must have. As far as I can tell, there is no discerning characteristic under `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` between iPad Air and iPad 2.

Comment: Unless there is a specific hardware device capability that you can specify via UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities then you need to support all iPad devices for an iPad app.  What is your specific requirement for iPad Air?  Processor speed?

Comment: I need the front facing camera to be at least 720p. My app using image recognition, and pre iPad Air cameras are only 640x480.

Comment: Then your app will have to do the best it can with the lower resolution camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` is the right way to go. Based on the list here:
[iOS Device Compatibility Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html), I guess you can use metal or opengles-3, which are both available only on iPad Air models but not on iPad 2.

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that those in the list. Thanks! Hopefully Apple approves.